# AWS SES out-of-the-office

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, email-bounces

1) How to distinguish between a Transient-General bounce and OOTO bounce(which also comes in as a Transient-General bounce)?

2) How to get the Body of an OOTO bounce ? We receive the bounce of this type but we also need to notify back to our user(original sender) about their intended recipient's OOTO status and possible details which could be in the OOTO email body(ex. I am on vacation from 08/10 to 08/20 and returning back on 08/21)?